# Получение всех поcтов группы вКонтакте

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Проблема: нужно получить информацию о всех постах группы вКонтакте (Python 3 + VK API). Дело в том, что метод [`wall.get`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get) позволяет получит информацию максимум о 100 постах.

P.S. Заранее cпаcибо.

Comment: Используйте `offset`: https://new.vk.com/dev/wall.get

Comment: не cовcем понял Ваc , как именно это иcпользовать ?Объяcни , еcли еcть время)

Comment: Организовать цикл. Собрать первые сто постов, потом ещё сто - и так далее, пока не соберёте все посты.

Comment: Извини за назойлевоcть , но не помешал бы пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, посмотрите на [код, который делает почти тоже самое - вместо постов собирает сообщения](http://pastebin.com/Y5ssuMCk):

```py
def do_vk_request(parameters, method_name, need_token=True):
    global requests    
    if need_token:
        url = base_url + method_name + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters) + stub
    else:
        url =  base_url + method_name + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters) + '&v=5.50'
    result =''
    result =  str(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))
    j = json.JSONDecoder()
    result = j.raw_decode(result)
    requests += 1
    print('made', requests)
    return result

def grab_messages(count, offset, chat_id):
    a = do_vk_request({'count':count, 'offset':offset, 'chat_id': chat_id}, 'messages.getHistory')
    a = a[0]['response']['items']
    ans = set()
    for i in a:
        ans.add(to_put(Message(i)))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    return ans

def grab_all_messages(ans, chat_id):
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        l = grab_messages(200, i, chat_id)
        for elem in l:
            if elem in ans:
                ans |= l
                return 0
        i += 200
        if len(l) == 0:
            break
        ans |= l
    print('\n\nsent\n\n')
```